# $f(z)$ is holomorphic, prove that $g(z) = \overline{f(\overline{z})}$ is holomorphic.

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

> $f(z)$ is holomorphic, prove that $g(z) = \overline{f(\overline{z})}$
>   is holomorphic.

**My attempt**

With $f(z) = f(x+iy) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ we get

$$g(z) =\overline{f(\overline{z})} = \overline{f(x+i(-y))} = u(x,-y) - iv(x,-y).$$

Since $f$ is holomorphic, it's true that
$$u'_x(x,y) = v'_y(x,y),$$
$$u'_y(x,y) = -v'_y(x,y).$$
For $g$ to be holomorphic the following must be true
$$u'_x(x,-y) = -v'_y(x,-y)$$
$$u'_y(x,-y) = v'_x(x,-y)$$

Using the Cauchy-Riemann equations for $f$ I get that
$$v'_y(x,-y) = -v'_y(x,-y),$$
$$-v'_x(x,-y) = v'_x(x,-y),$$
must be true for $g$ to be holomorphic, but this can only true for $v'_x = v'_y = 0$ no?

**How can I make my solution work? Is there a better (simple) way?**

Comment: Step 0: use a notation that prevents a confusion of the real/imaginary parts of $f$ and of $g$. Say $g(x+iy) = a(x,y) + ib(x,y)$. Alternatives: Use the Wirtinger derivatives, if you know them, or - if you know that holomorphic functions are analytic - power series.

Comment: I second the last method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method should work, if you took the partial derivatives correctly. You should use the chain rule for partial derivatives, there lies your mistake.

Your function is $g(x,y) = u(x,-y)+ i( - v(x,-y))= a(x,y) + i b(x,y)$. (We use other letters so we are not confused). Now calculate the partials:

$$ \frac{\partial a}{\partial x}(x,y) = \frac{\partial }{\partial x}( u(x,-y)) = u_x(x,-y) \\
\frac{\partial a}{\partial y}(x,y) = \frac{\partial }{\partial y}( u(x,-y)) = -u_y(x,-y)\\
\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}(x,y) = \frac{\partial }{\partial x}( -v(x,-y)) =-v_x(x,-y)\\
\frac{\partial b}{\partial y}(x,y) = \frac{\partial }{\partial y}( -v(x,-y)) = v_y(x,-y)
$$

It should be clear now how to use the C-R equations.

Comment: Thank you, no idea how I could miss that.

Answer (score 5):

You can prove it by definition:

$\dfrac{g(z+h)-g(z)}{h}=\dfrac{\overline{f}(\overline{z}+\overline{h})-\overline{f}(\overline{z})}{h}=\overline{\Big(\dfrac{f(\overline{z}+\overline{h})-f(\overline{z})}{\overline{h}}\Big)}$. Using that $f$ is differentiable at $\overline{z}$, you are done.

Comment: Wow that was clean, thank you. Do you see what is wrong with my solution? According to a hint in my textbook, I should be able to use the Cauchy Riemann Equations

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f(z)$ is holomorphic iff $\frac{df(z)}{d\bar{z}}=0$ or $\frac{df(\bar{z})}{dz}=0$. So
$$ \frac{dg(z)}{d\bar{z}}=\frac{d\overline{f(\bar{z})}}{d\bar{z}}=\overline{\left(\frac{df(\bar{z})}{dz}\right)}=0 $$
and hence $g(z)$ is holomorphic.